# How do I access the Button text after setting it in "onTimeSet" method?

Tags: android, android-studio

My Code

```
timePickerBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =  new TimePickerDialog(NewTaskActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int Minute) {
                TimeHour = hourOfDay;
                TimeMinute = Minute;

                Calendar calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendarTime.set(0,0,0, TimeHour, TimeMinute);
                timePickerBTN.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendarTime));

            }

        },12,0,false);


        timePickerDialog.updateTime(TimeHour, TimeMinute);
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }


});
```

I want to access the **timePickerBTN** text after I set it *timePickerBTN.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendarTime));* in **OnTimeSet**

I want to set the **timePickerBTN** text (After picking time) as TextView text

(EDIT) Tried This Method Too
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvcA3.png)

Comment: Declare your String outside onCreate, you need to check out for local variable and global variable

Answer (score 0):

Use getText() to get the text of Button i.e.

```
String text = timePickerBTN.getText().toString();
```

Your code would look like this

```
  timePickerBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =  new TimePickerDialog(NewTaskActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int Minute) {
                        TimeHour = hourOfDay;
                        TimeMinute = Minute;

                        Calendar calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendarTime.set(0,0,0, TimeHour, TimeMinute);
                        timePickerBTN.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendarTime));
                        text = timePickerBTN.getText().toString();

                    }

                },12,0,false);


                timePickerDialog.updateTime(TimeHour, TimeMinute);
                timePickerDialog.show();

            }


        });
```

Comment: I tried the above method but I want to access that string outside the method so that I can send that String value info Firebase database and later set It as textview text. Adding this String text = timePickerBTN.getText().toString(); doesn't allow me to set that string as String mTimeText = text.

Comment: Declare String text; outside onCreate()